# Trigger Error: External entry point: public void invoke(): executed 1 time in 321 ms

Tags: apex, trigger, class

When trying to save a record, I am shown the error `insufficient access rights on cross-reference id` (WITHOUT an ID). When checking the apex debug logs, I see the error `External entry point: public void invoke(): executed 1 time in 321 ms` after a beforeInsert trigger finishes. The AfterInsert trigger is not reached, so I think the problem is somewhere in between BeforeInsert and our validation rules.

The next line of the error references the first line in our custom object's trigger: `Trigger.BTAssetAllocations: line 2, column 1: public static void triggerHandler(System.Type): executed 1 time in 222 ms`. I'm not sure why the trigger is called again, since we have already entered the trigger.

Important note: When I save the record as an Admin, it works. But when I sign in as a regular user, they see that error, but I can't see in the code where we are attempting to do DML that could cause a problem, and the error message references the trigger. Another note is that we are using the fflib library.

**Does anyone know what the issue might be? Full debug log below**

**Edit: Query and FFLIB line that is returning the error below:**

Query:

```
public List<BT_Asset_Allocation__c> selectBTAssetAllocationByAssetId(Set<Id> assetIds) {
        fflib_QueryFactory qf = newQueryFactory(false, false, true)
                .selectFields(getSObjectFieldList())
                .selectFields(ASSET_RELATED_FIELDS)
                .setCondition('BT_Asset__c IN :assetIds')
                .setOrdering('Projected_End_Date__c', fflib_QueryFactory.SortOrder.ASCENDING, false); //NULLS FIRST is default?
        return Database.query(qf.toSOQL());
    }
```

And the line that's breaking in fflib_QueryFactory:

```
/**
     * Returns a QueryFactory configured with the Selectors object, fields, fieldsets and default order by
     * CRUD and FLS read security will be checked if the corresponding inputs are true (overrides that defined in the selector).
     **/
    public fflib_QueryFactory newQueryFactory(Boolean assertCRUD, Boolean enforceFLS, Boolean includeSelectorFields)
    {
        // Construct QueryFactory around the given SObject
        return configureQueryFactory( //<- Line that's breaking
            new fflib_QueryFactory(getSObjectType2()), 
                assertCRUD, enforceFLS, includeSelectorFields);
    }
```

**Full debug below:**

```
List<String>:_static_ASSET_RELATED_FIELDS:0
  String:_static_ASSET_RETURN_BODY:0
  String:_static_ASSET_RETURN_SUBJECT:0
  List<String>:_static_CANDIDATE_RELATED_FIELDS:0
  Integer:_static_DAYS_BETWEEN_EMAILS:0
  fflib_SObjectDomain.ErrorFactory:_static_Errors:0
  String:_static_INVALID_ALLOCATION_ERROR:0
  fflib_SObjectDomain.TestFactory:_static_Test:0
  Map<System.Type,fflib_SObjectDomain.TriggerEvent>:_static_TriggerEventByClass:0
  Map<System.Type,List<fflib_SObjectDomain>>:_static_TriggerStateByClass:0
  Map<String,fflib_SObjectDescribe>:_static_instanceCache:0
  char[]:digits:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  int[]:sizeTable:0

18:03:49.322 (322596524)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
18:03:49.0 (327063397)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|BTAssetAllocations on BT_Asset_Allocation trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/BTAssetAllocations
18:03:49.0 (360309148)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|TRIGGERS
18:03:49.0 (360337111)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOQL operations
18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML operations
18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations
External entry point: public void invoke(): executed 1 time in 321 ms
Trigger.BTAssetAllocations: line 2, column 1: public static void triggerHandler(System.Type): executed 1 time in 222 ms
Class.fflib_SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 321, column 1: private static void triggerHandler(System.Type, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, List<SObject>, Map<Id,SObject>): executed 1 time in 221 ms
Class.fflib_SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 368, column 1: public void handleBeforeInsert(): executed 1 time in 192 ms
Class.fflib_SObjectDomain.handleBeforeInsert: line 176, column 1: public void onBeforeInsert(): executed 1 time in 192 ms
Class.BTAssetAllocations.onBeforeInsert: line 42, column 1: public List<SObject> __sfdc_Records(): executed 2 times in 153 ms
Class.BTAssetUpdates.checkBTAssetAvailability: line 76, column 1: global BTAssetAllocationsSelector(): executed 2 times in 101 ms
Class.BTAssetAllocationsSelector.selectBTAssetAllocationByAssetId: line 46, column 1: public fflib_QueryFactory selectFields(List<String>): executed 1 time in 33 ms
Class.fflib_QueryFactory.selectFields: line 240, column 1: private String getFieldPath(String): executed 8 times in 33 ms
Class.BTAssetAllocationsSelector.selectBTAssetAllocationByAssetId: line 44, column 1: public fflib_QueryFactory newQueryFactory(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean): executed 1 time in 26 ms
Class.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1: private fflib_QueryFactory configureQueryFactory(fflib_QueryFactory, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean): executed 1 time in 23 ms

18:03:49.362 (362158073)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END
```

Comment: The stack trace looks reversed; the issue would be in the last line fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory and would have something to do with the selector class.  I'd check to make sure you check the running user's permissions versus the objecttype(s) and also that the FLS setting in the selector does what you want

Comment: @cropredy Thank you, i updated the question with the line in FFblib class which is failing. I already had the FLS adn CRUD enforcement set to false

Comment: so, what permissions does the user have on `BT_Asset_Allocation__c`?

Comment: @cropredy they have at least read access to every single field being queried for

Comment: and R(ead) access on the object?

Comment: Yes, they even have modify all records for BT Asset Allocaiton

Comment: As an experiment, replace the selector method with static SOQL. This looks like a permissions issue and the stack trace may be misleading

Comment: @cropredy It turns out those debugs i added are not actually errors! We set the finest debug log so it outputs the execution times for methods, so those are not actually relevant. I think you're right about it being a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fflib framework enforces CRUD by default. So if your method **selectBTAssetAllocationByAssetId** in your class **BTAssetAllocationsSelector** queries an object or field for which the read permission is not set in the regular user's profile or permission set, then the error is thrown.

To disable the CRUD enforcement, use the solution provided under **Option 1** in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/267086/90791) for your **BTAssetAllocationsSelector** class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i already had crud and fls enforcing disabled. I updated the question with that code, and with the exact line in the fflib class where it seems to be breaking